# How to split an array in unequal pieces?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like this

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 3, 2, 1])
```

I want to split it in three pieces

```
x1 = array([1, 2, 3])
x2 = array([99, 99])
x3 = array([3, 2, 1])
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How do you decide about the size of the output arrays (why 3-2-3 and not 3-3-2 or any other option)?

Comment: One naïve way, of many possible ways: `[x[:3], x[3:5], x[5:]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 3, 2, 1])

x1, x2, x3 = np.split(x, [3, 5])
```

`[3, 5]` thereby specifies the indexes at which you want to split.

That yields

```
x1
array([1, 2, 3])

x2
array([99, 99])

x3
array([3, 2, 1])
```